# Silverlight DataGrid no DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlightcontrols

In Silverlight there is no DataGridComboBoxColumn in the DataGrid.

This is sad. What is the best way to recreate this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a specific class. Use a DataGridTemplateColumn and set the template to have a combobox.